# Ubicar fila en tabla php sin id

Tags: php

Como haria para ubicar una fila en una tabla que se arma de la siguiente forma:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:740px !IMPORTANT; overflow:scroll; border:1px solid #FF6600;" class="display2">
  <tr style="background:yellow">
    <td align="center">9045</td>
    <td style="padding:2px 6px; width:15%; text-align:center;" class="jugador6275">Sr contreras</td>
    <td align="center">
      <table class="puntos">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" style="padding-right:14px;border-width:1px; width:50%; border:none;"><b style="font-size:14px">&nbsp5</b></td>
          <td align="right" style="padding-left:14px; width:50%; border:none; "><span style="color:blue">3</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <table class="puntos">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" style="padding-right:14px;border-width:1px; width:50%; border:none;"><b style="font-size:14px">&nbsp8</b></td>
          <td align="right" style="padding-left:14px; width:50%; border:none; "><span style="color:blue">3</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <table class="puntos">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" style="padding-right:14px;border-width:1px; width:50%; border:none;"><b style="font-size:14px">&nbsp5</b></td>
          <td align="right" style="padding-left:14px; width:50%; border:none; "><span style="color:red">0</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <table class="puntos">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" style="padding-right:14px;border-width:1px; width:50%; border:none;"><b style="font-size:14px">&nbsp3</b></td>
          <td align="right" style="padding-left:14px; width:50%; border:none; "><span style="color:blue">3</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <table class="puntos">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" style="padding-right:14px;border-width:1px; width:50%; border:none;"><b style="font-size:14px">&nbsp5</b></td>
          <td align="right" style="padding-left:14px; width:50%; border:none; "><span style="color:red">0</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <table class="puntos">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" style="padding-right:14px;border-width:1px; width:50%; border:none;"><b style="font-size:14px">&nbsp8</b></td>
          <td align="right" style="padding-left:14px; width:50%; border:none; "><span style="color:blue">1</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="color: #fff; background:#0099FF;"><b style="color: #fff; font-size:13px">10</td></b></tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero ubicar la fila basandome en el resultado de la primera columna que en este caso es 9045 pero puede ser otro. Generalmente las ubico con document.getElementById anadiendo un id a cada fila, pero esta tabla se arma con una consulta de la base de datos y eso no puedo modificarlo. Lo que busco es ubicar una serie de elementos para pintar las filas relacionadas al usuario que ingreso.

Comment: No tienes posibilidad alguna de poder agregar el id?, piense que si busca el valor en toda la tabla, existe la posibilidad que encuentre resultados repetidos y eso genere conflictos

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende bien. ¿Tendrías que recorrer las primeras columnas de varias filas de la tabla hasta encontrar ese valor? ¿O bien tendrías que encontrar **siempre** el valor de la primera columna de la tabla? ¿Habría una sola tabla en el DOM, habría más de una tabla? ¿Si habría más de una tabla, qué posición ocuparía la tabla en cuestión en el DOM?  Es información imprescindible que debería constar en tu pregunta para darte una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: No amigo ese valor es único,  no se repide.

Comment: Es una secuencia de filas pueden ser cientos o unas decenas. Solo puse una fila para que detallaran como se arma la fila. Y solo busco resaltar las asociadas al usuario que puede ser ninguna o muchas.

Comment: Además, la tabla que presentas es, con todo respeto, **desastrosa**: Tienes una etiqueta `table` de apertura, y dentro de ella tienes un `tr` en el cual, antes de cerrarlo metes un `td` y dentro de él metes otro `table`... en fin, un verdadero desastre que deberías corregir porque así es imposible trabajar los datos. **No puedes meter un elemento `table` dentro de un `td` que está a su vez dentro de un `tr`**. ¡Estás queriendo llevar un avión en una bicicleta!

Comment: Si comprendo su punto de vista, tambien pienso lo mismo pero ese código viene así de la base de datos y se imprime generando la tabla.

Comment: ¿No tienes acceso al código que recibe los datos y los imprime? Trabajar sobre datos erróneos o mal formados puede resultar ser peligroso. Será un código ambiguo, inseguro, que podría tener comportamientos inesperados según el caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano Temo que estás diciendo algo que no es cierto, la **w3c  nunca dice que no se pueda colocar una tabla dentro de otra, y precisamente anidado en un td es la única forma** Ahora **no deja de ser un código desastroso** eso es cierto. En cuanto al problema, que código haz intentado? Debe ser Js, Jquery o Php?

Comment: @EdgarGutiérrez no he revisado la w3c al respecto, pero así como quizá no lo diga, no creo que tampoco lo aliente. Y no estoy seguro de que un código así valide, es muy probable que dé error, al menos en la validación. Además no veo ningún caso en el que sea necesario *transportar un avión en una bicicleta*. Me parece que es algo de sentido común. Y en cuanto a código, no imagino qué resultado puede dar el que intentes *buscar la tabla que es hija de una columna*. Quizá lo hagas funcionar, pero será siempre un código precario, ilegible y desastroso: arreglar un desastre con otro desastre.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el selector de primer hijo de css: `:first-child` o `:nth-child(1)` y preguntar si tiene el valor igual al que necesitas y si es positivo, añadir una clase usando el selector `.parent` de **jquery**:

así:

```
var celda1ra = $('td:nth-child(1)');

celda1ra.each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == '456') {
        $(this).parent().addClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

Acá un ejemplo visual:

```js
$('td:nth-child(1)').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == '456') {
        $(this).parent().addClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

```css
table, table *{
  border: solid 1px gray;
}

.highlight{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>456</td>
   <td>212</td>
   <td>87</td>
   <td>39</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>25</td>
   <td>45</td>
   <td>978</td>
   <td>25</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>87</td>
   <td>456</td>
   <td>98</td>
   <td>12</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Si te fijas, estoy preguntando por el valor `456` y aunque está ubicado en dos filas, solo me selecciona la fila cuando la primera celda es la que contiene el valor.

Ahora si tienes en la primera celda otras anidaciones o tablas, puedes usar el selector parents y especificar un criterio que se cumpla una sola vez, por ejemplo:

.parents('table').parents('tr')

Lo anterior significa que va a seleccionar el `table` ancestro más cercano y a partir de este, seleccionar un `tr` más cercano. Ejemplo:

```js
$('td:first-child td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == '456') {
        $(this).parents('table').parents('tr').addClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

```css
table, table *{
  border: solid 1px gray;
}

.highlight{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>456</td>
   <td>212</td>
   <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td>39</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>25</td>
   <td>45</td>
   <td>978</td>
   <td>25</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td>87</td>
   <td>98</td>
   <td>12</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>21</td>
   <td>768</td>
   <td>09</td>
   <td>356</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

¿Es esto lo que necesitabas?

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funciona, y como haria para seleccionar todos los que cumplan la misma condicion, por ejemplo para marcar las dos fila que tienen '456'

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre algo como agregar una clase a td e iterar sobre la clase, haciendo la búsqueda, algo así

```
$('.td_class').each(function(i, obj) {
    var val = $(this).text();
    if (val == "id") {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    }
});
```

creo que podría funcionar